# Serve SOAP from ASP.NET Core web method

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, asp.net-core

In classic ASP.NET, we would simply mark a method with the `WebMethod` attribute to create a SOAP service method that could be called from an external app. How do we achieve the same with ASP.NET Core?

It must be XML SOAP based. It must be compatible with a client that worked when ASP.NET class was the back end.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the [SOAPCore](https://github.com/DigDes/SoapCore) NuGet package to achieve that. Imagine you have a contract like below:

```cs
[ServiceContract]
public interface IPingService
{
    [OperationContract]
    string Ping(string msg);
}
```

And the implementation:

```cs
public class SampleService : IPingService
{
    public string Ping(string msg)
    {
        return string.Join(string.Empty, msg.Reverse());
    }
}
```

And then registration of the service:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     services.AddSingleton(new PingService());
     services.AddMvc();
     //rest goes here
}
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env,  ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    app.UseSoapEndpoint(path: "/PingService.svc", binding: new BasicHttpBinding());
    app.UseMvc();
    //rest goes here
}
```

#### Further Reading

- [How to Call WCF Services and Create SOAP Services with ASP.NET Core](https://stackify.com/soap-net-core/)
- [Custom ASP.NET Core Middleware Example](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/09/19/custom-asp-net-core-middleware-example/)

Comment: Hmmm.... This looks like WCF. I can already serve up WCF. Perhaps I'm missing something. Could I perhaps just serve up a WCF service with BassicHttpBinding?

Comment: Is it possible to get a complex deeply nested XML document as the output from an incoming request using SoapCore?  For example, let say we only want a few elements out of a complex SOAP request and want the entire request body (no envelope) for parsing via Xpath.  Can your function Ping receive a XElement of the SOAP body?  I've been playing with SoapCore and it seems like you have to create a hierarchy of models that match the XML hierarchy.

Comment: @mtpultz I am not sure off the top of my head. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks @CodingYoshi I ended up adding a Tuner service and grabbing the raw request and parsing it using Xpath.  It's clumsy since it have to parse out the soap envelope and body tags, but it works well enough and doesn't require deserializing into a set of models.  Thanks for the response

Answer (score 1):

Extending the Solution proposed by @CodingYoshi which is great.

When I install SoapCore i had to install all the dependencies first here is the list:

```sh
Install-Package Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives -Version 2.2.0 
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features -Version 2.2.0 
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions -Version 2.2.0 
Install-Package Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers -Version 2.2.0 
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities -Version 2.2.0 
Install-Package Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions -version 2.2.0 
Install-Package Microsoft.Extensions.ObjectPool -Version 2.2.0 
Install-Package Microsoft.Extensions.Options -Version 2.2.0 
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http -Version 2.2.2  
Install-Package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions -Version 2.2.0
Install-Package SoapCore -Version 0.9.9.5
```

Then on my `Startup.cs` I added this:

```cs
app.UseSoapEndpoint<IMyService>("/IMyService.svc", new BasicHttpBinding(), SoapSerializer.XmlSerializer);
app.UseSoapEndpoint<IMyService>("/IMyService.svc", new BasicHttpBinding(), SoapSerializer.XmlSerializer);
app.UseSoapEndpoint<IMyService>("/V3/IMyService.svc", new BasicHttpBinding(), SoapSerializer.XmlSerializer);

app.UseMvc();
```